# Django Template comparing value issues

Tags: html, django

> Good day! I would like to ask why this code is not returning True even if the condition is equal in Django template. I have tried displaying the output of each and confirmed that the if-else condition is being satisfied. Please see attached picture for the sample output[image]

```
{% if core.username == username %}
     Same. ---- {{ core.username }} == {{ username }}
{% else %}
     Different. --- {{ core.username }} == {{ username }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: At lease one of them is object, not a string. Please show corresponding view code.